# Difference in resize between jquery 1.4.4 and 1.7.2

Tags: jquery

I have been using JQuery 1.4.4 js file and when I do resize my element went transparent and do resize. Because I started to use FlexiGrid needed to update version of JQuery to 1.6.2. Now when I do resize of element it just do it without going transparent and showing me position and look of new element. With JQuery 1.7.2 it doesn't do resize anymore.

How to keep functionality of resize from 1.4.4 and have possibility to use FlexiGrid?

I searched on Internet but doesn't found similar problem.

Tryed to change UI js but it doesn't depend of it.

Comment: When you say `resize` do you mean the event handler, or some form of plugin? More clear information is needed please.

Comment: event handler. I didn't used any aditional plugins.

Comment: I done different include only for that page with old JQuery and all other use new one. It is fastest. I also saw that JQuery calendar use 1.3.2 version. possible that newer versions have some kind of bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done different include only for that page with old JQuery and all other use new one. It is fastest. I also saw that JQuery calendar use 1.3.2 version. possible that newer versions have some kind of bug.